# SQLite transactions fail

Tags: r, sqlite, transactions

I'm performing thousands of calculations with R and some external software. 
To keep track of this, I have constructed a pipeline in R on a SQLite3 database.
To get things done, I've set it up to allow for multiple nodes on our computing cluster to run the R script. 
Naturally, we need to keep things atomized so I am actively starting transactions.

To avoid the script from crashing when trying to get a lock on the database, I have the following code that attempts to begin a transaction, and if fails, waits and then retries:

```
dbBeginTransaction <- function(dbconn, state='DEFERRED', timeout=5, retries=10) {
  state <- toupper(state)
  if (!state %in% c('DEFERRED','IMMEDIATE','EXCLUSIVE')) stop('Attempt at illegal transaction.')
  res <- NULL
  exit <- FALSE
  for (i in 1:retries) {
    try(
      res <- dbSendQuery(dbconn, paste('BEGIN',state,'TRANSACTION;'))
      , silent=TRUE
    )
    # res is null if above query fails.
    err <- dbGetException(dbconn)
    if (err$errorNum == 0) { ## OK
      #return(TRUE)
      exit <- TRUE
      break
    } else if (err$errorNum == 5) {  ## Database locked.
      if (i == retries+1) {
        cat('Database still locked after',i,'attempts.\n',file=stderr())
        #return(FALSE)
        exit <- FALSE
        break
      } else {
        Sys.sleep(timeout)
      }
    } else {
      ## errorNum == 1 ## Already within transaction.
      cat(err$errorMsg, '\n',  file = stderr())
      #return(FALSE)
      exit <- FALSE
      break
    }
  }
  invisible(exit)
}


  ## Usage:
  insert_results <- function(results) {
    ## Some preparing of results
    if (dbBeginTransaction(conn, 'EXCLUSIVE') == FALSE) return(FALSE)
    dbSendPreparedQuery(conn, 'INSERT INTO results (...) VALUES (...);', results)
    dbCommit(conn)
  }

  ## After a computation:
  results <- magic()
  if (!insert_results(results)) stop('Could not save results')
```

When debugging, it works as it should. But every now and then I get this odd error, and the script crashes:

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement, bind.data) :
  rsqlite_query_send: could not execute: database is locked
Calls: dbSendPreparedQuery ... dbSendPreparedQuery -> .local -> sqliteSendQuery -> .Call
Execution halted
```

I cannot fathom what happens, and I am yet to reproduce the error.
The error is clear, but I would have thought that my routine had prevented it.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

I'm running R under linux, as seen by:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_US
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US     LC_MONETARY=en_US    LC_MESSAGES=en_US
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US       LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] RSQLite_1.0.0 DBI_0.3.1
```

Comment: Why don't you just use [PRAGMA busy_timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout)?

Comment: Because I apparently haven't read the documentation thoroughly. :) As far as I can read, this circumvents my dbBeginTransaction routine?

Comment: Update: Using the PRAGMA solved the issue and I threw my function on the code-dump.

Answer (score -2):

Encountered this problem today in the office today. This is the suggestion of my colleague: It can be solved by making sure that every time you do a database connection and make some sort of change to the database you do a dbCommit(con). The new code would look like this:

```
dbBeginTransaction <- function(dbconn, state='DEFERRED', timeout=5, retries=10) {
  state <- toupper(state)
  if (!state %in% c('DEFERRED','IMMEDIATE','EXCLUSIVE')) stop('Attempt at illegal transaction.')
  res <- NULL
  exit <- FALSE
  for (i in 1:retries) {
    try(
      dbBegin(dbconn)
      res <- dbSendQuery(dbconn, paste('BEGIN',state,'TRANSACTION;'))
      , silent=TRUE
    )
    # res is null if above query fails.
    err <- dbGetException(dbconn)
    if (err$errorNum == 0) { ## OK
      #return(TRUE)
      exit <- TRUE
      break
    } else if (err$errorNum == 5) {  ## Database locked.
      if (i == retries+1) {
        cat('Database still locked after',i,'attempts.\n',file=stderr())
        #return(FALSE)
        exit <- FALSE
        break
      } else {
        Sys.sleep(timeout)
      }
    } else {
      ## errorNum == 1 ## Already within transaction.
      cat(err$errorMsg, '\n',  file = stderr())
      #return(FALSE)
      exit <- FALSE
      break
    }
  }
  invisible(exit)
}


  ## Usage:
  insert_results <- function(results) {
    ## Some preparing of results
    if (dbBeginTransaction(conn, 'EXCLUSIVE') == FALSE) return(FALSE)
    dbSendPreparedQuery(conn, 'INSERT INTO results (...) VALUES (...);', results)
    dbCommit(conn)
  }

  ## After a computation:
  results <- magic()
  if (!insert_results(results)) stop('Could not save results')
```

And I solved by adding dbBegin(con) just before your begin any transactions with the database

```
dbBeginTransaction <- function(dbconn, state='DEFERRED', timeout=5, retries=10) {
  state <- toupper(state)
  if (!state %in% c('DEFERRED','IMMEDIATE','EXCLUSIVE')) stop('Attempt at illegal transaction.')
  res <- NULL
  exit <- FALSE
  for (i in 1:retries) {
    try(
      res <- dbSendQuery(dbconn, paste('BEGIN',state,'TRANSACTION;'))
      , silent=TRUE
      dbCommit(dbconn)
    )
    # res is null if above query fails.
    err <- dbGetException(dbconn)
    if (err$errorNum == 0) { ## OK
      #return(TRUE)
      exit <- TRUE
      break
    } else if (err$errorNum == 5) {  ## Database locked.
      if (i == retries+1) {
        cat('Database still locked after',i,'attempts.\n',file=stderr())
        #return(FALSE)
        exit <- FALSE
        break
      } else {
        Sys.sleep(timeout)
      }
    } else {
      ## errorNum == 1 ## Already within transaction.
      cat(err$errorMsg, '\n',  file = stderr())
      #return(FALSE)
      exit <- FALSE
      break
    }
  }
  invisible(exit)
}


  ## Usage:
  insert_results <- function(results) {
    ## Some preparing of results
    if (dbBeginTransaction(conn, 'EXCLUSIVE') == FALSE) return(FALSE)
    dbSendPreparedQuery(conn, 'INSERT INTO results (...) VALUES (...);', results)
    dbCommit(conn)
  }

  ## After a computation:
  results <- magic()
  if (!insert_results(results)) stop('Could not save results')
```

Comment: ``dbBegin`` begins a transaction; the following ``BEGIN TRANSACTION;`` query would result in an error as you cannot begin two transaction ("Error: cannot start a transaction within a transaction"). The following ``dbCommit`` _ends_ the transaction, leaving us where we started - transaction-less.

Comment: Replace `dbBeginTransaction` with `dbBegin` dbBeginTransaction is  old perhaps that would work.

Comment: I am not using the old ``dbBeginTransaction``; I am only referencing my own ``dbBeginTransction`` function.